# Will Fourier Series converge even if you only use Prime Integer frequencies?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, fourier-series

So there is a Fourier Series for a function $f(x)$ with period $P$:

$$
f(x) = \frac{A_0}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^{N} A_n \cdot \cos \left(\frac{n 2 \pi x}{P} + \phi_n \right) 
$$

Let $\frac{2 \pi x}{P} = t$ then

$$
f(x) = \frac{A_0}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^{N} A_n \cdot \cos \left(n t(x) + \phi_n \right) 
$$

Suppose that for this particular function $f(x)$ the series converges, and my question is the following:

If I only use prime numbers for my frequencies $n$, will the series still converge? Even if it needs to be longer than the original one?

Comment: No. If it did, you would have two distinct Fourier series for the same function; but the Fourier series for a given function is unique.

Comment: Consider the following. Imagine an infinite fourier series, a complete one, for $f(x)$. If we take only the prime frequencies, but leaving the coefficients as they are, as if we HAD the complete transform, but chose only to use the prime frequencies in the series. It's not as if it was a different series, just a slice of the complete one. I know it won't converge perfectly, but will it converge assymptotically to the correct $f(x)$?

Comment: No! Why on earth do you think it should?

Comment: Well I know that the series converge when you have infinite terms. So when you truncate the series, you don't have the whole series any longer. You can, for example, drop higher harmonics and the series starts getting less and less like the function, but if you put the terms back in, it gets more and more like back again. When you have a sequence with only primes, as long as the coefficients for the prime frequencies are correct, shouldn't it at least look like $f(x)$, and the more primes you have (with correct coefficients), shouldn't it look like $f(x)$ more and more, even if asymptotically?

Comment: I suggest that you seriously consider abandoning this idea.

Comment: It's not really an idea to do anything with. I just wanted to understand why that isn't so. More like a mind experiment regarding Fourier Series properties and limits, that's all. Just a plaything. Eveyrthing that can be said about it, is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As TonyK said, the series of prime-numbered terms will converge to a different function, because a Fourier series of $f$ is unique. Unless, of course, we had $A_n=0$ for all composite $n$.

Indeed, the new sum, call it $g$, will be orthogonal to every trigonometric polynomial $\cos \left(n t(x) + \phi_n \right)$ with composite $n$. If the original series had $A_n\ne 0$ for some composite $n$, then we have a lower bound on the modulus of $\int (f-g) \cos \left(n t(x) + \phi_n \right)$, which gives us a quantitative way of saying that $g$ will not be very close to $f$.